# Not able to start SQL Agent Service

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2014

I want to connect to a SQL server that is deployed on Azure. But I am getting a network connection error.

I realized that SQL agent is not getting restarted in the Services and gives the below error.

In SQL Server configuration Manager when I try to start SQL Agent it gives the below error.

[image]

Comment: I think SQL Agent won't supported in Express edition. Can you re verify that which edition of SQL Server you are using?

Comment: Then which SQL version do I need to download? I am using SQL Server 2014. Now I am not sure if SQL Server 2014 installs SQL Express. Could you please help on which SQL version should I download?

Comment: This is the verion of my MS SQL 10.0.1600.22

Answer (score 0):

SQL agent is not supported in sql express version, so it won't start there (from what i see on one of the screens sql version is express.

For the help to Your problem -> try to configure firewall to allow access to port 1433.

Comment: I created an exception for port 1433. But still it isnt working. Any suggestions on which SQL should I download or use? Currently I am using SQL Server 2014 and I am not sure if it installs SQL Express by default.